# Apigee Oauth2.0 testing using Trace tool

Tags: oauth, apigee

can any one please suggest how do i test oauth2.0 by using Apigee edge management Trace tool or web browser. I do not  have access to post man rest client or curl.

kindly help.

Comment: How are you currently testing or consuming other API services?  Obviously you need some way to access the API (either client tools like postman or curl) or in server code like javascript or lwp...

Answer (score 0):

You can go to http://apigee.com/console.

Apigee console works as a Oauth 2 client as well.

To make it work against your APIs, you need to sign in. After you sign in to the console, you see a "Create your own API Console" link at the top right corner of the screen.

Once you are done defining the client with client_id, secret, redirect url etc. you can launch your version of apigee console and test Oauth 2.0 compliant APIs.